# How to get class of job that updated a model (triggering an observer)?

Tags: laravel

I am currently working with Laravel Queue jobs that save a model. I use an observer `onUpdate(Model $model)` to detect the changes and if that update is performed by a job or in console `if (App::runningInConsole())`.

How can I determine which class called the `->save()` method and triggered the observer?

Comment: can you share the job class? i want to see where you are firing the event

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you fire your event, but using `Jobs Event`, you can react when a job is fired and to which job has been fired.

you can check eveything here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-events

what I suggest is to call your event on Queue::after sos you retrieve the job name

```php
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
            event( new my_event ( get_class( $event->job ) ) );
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, but I had to update my question, because it was a bit faulty and not precise at all. I think now it is understandable.